# Nesting an Array in Storybook React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, storybook

I'm struggling to pass values to my nested array in Storybook js. What's the proper way to write this?

The component:

```
{options.map(item => {
    return <div id={item.id}>
            <div>…</div>
            <div className="ml-2">
                {actions.map(subitem => {
                    return <Button
                            id={subitem.id}
                        />
                })}
            </div>
    </div>
})}
```

The story:

```
Basics.args = {
    options: [
        {
            id: 'a',
            actions: [
                {
                  id: ‘b’,
                },
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Question seems a bit unclear to me. What do you mean by passing values to a nested array? From the code snippet it seems like you are iterating over  two separate arrays and using the values  in your JSX. What kind of issue are you facing? Is there an error being raised?

Comment: In the component's story, I'm able to set a value of `item.id`, but I'm unable to get to `subitem.id`. The error I get is `actions is undefined`, but setting the `actions` property type doesn't have any effect.

Comment: it will be item.actions.map since your action array is a property of your item object.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get `item.actions is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actions` is not defined in your code. Since actions is a property of the item object you should use

```
item.actions.map
```

I have attached a code snippet for your reference.

```js
  const arr = {
   options: [
        {
            id: 'a',
            actions: [
                {
                  id: 'b',
                },
            ]
        } ]
  }

arr.options.map(item=> item.actions.map(subitem => console.log(subitem.id)))
```

Comment: That helped! Mine wasn't working because I had an incomplete second object. Thanks for helping out!